# Joomla editor not showing image, read more and insert module tab

Tags: joomla-2.5, editor, tinymce

Using below code to display editor

```
$editor =& JFactory::getEditor();
$params = array( 'smilies'=> '0' ,
     'style'  => '1' ,  
     'layer'  => '0' , 
     'table'  => '0' ,
     'clear_entities'=>'0'
     );
    echo $editor->display( 'desc', '', '400', '400', '20', '20', false, null, null, null, $params );
```

But facing only one issue 
Using this way its not showing these 3 tabs below editor i.e

1. Insert Module
2. Image
3. Read  More

see screenshot, can any one advise how to get added the tabs of Insert module, image and read more below editor

[image]

As i checked source code

```
  <div id="editor-xtd-buttons">
```

and the relevant code under it is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `false` to `true` in your last line:

```
echo $editor->display( 'desc', '', '400', '400', '20', '20', true, null, null, null, $params );
```

Here's a quick screenshot from Joomla 2.5. Note that according to your screenshot, your default editor seems to be JCE, not TinyMCE.

[image]